# VSTO Excel Add-in Won't Load

Tags: excel, vsto, add-in

I'm currently working on a VSTO Excel add-in project. The add-in was successfully installed by our users. The problem is, only the admin users can view the add-in, non-admin users can't seem to load the add-in, loadbehavior always sets to 2. The non-admin users can't also set the VSTO system environment to enable logging.

Am I missing a step in the installation process?
Is there a workaround for this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: how is addin getting installed?

Answer (score 0):

Did you use Click once or MSI? Check you registry if they are added under HKEY_CURRENT_USER?
If it is then you have modify your deployment to add the entry under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE

Check this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mshneer/archive/2007/09/04/deploying-your-vsto-add-in-to-all-users-part-i.aspx